# Unable to access DataReader when calling a Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, enterprise-library

I am building a app and am trying utilize Enterprise Lib 6 for my data access.

It works great when I use a SQL command but can't get it to work with a stored procedure.

I've traced the code and it seems like the data reader doesn't get populated.

I'm sure I'm just missing something dumb but any help would be appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Trainer.Classes.Database
{
  public class Staff
  {
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    public int ValidateUser(string userName, string password)
    {
      string storedProcName = "uspUtilityVersionNumberGet";
      string sqlStatement = "SELECT VersionNumber FROM UTILITY_VERSION";

      // Create an instanct of the database
      DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
      SqlDatabase DB = factory.CreateDefault() as SqlDatabase;

      //using (DbCommand cmd = DB.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlStatement))
      //{
      //  DB.AddOutParameter(cmd, "VersionNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

      //  using (IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
      //  {
      //    if (dr.Read())
      //      return 0;
      //    else
      //      return -9;
      //  }
      //}

      using (DbCommand cmd = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcName))
      {
        DB.AddOutParameter(cmd, "VersionNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

        using (IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
          if (dr.Read())
            return 0;
          else
            return -9;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "but can't get it to work with a stored procedure" <-- what does this mean exactly. You need to include detailed information, not just 'it does not work'.

Comment: What *actually* happens? Does `Read()` return `false` when you expect `true`? Or does it throw an exception? or...? Also: is the reply mechanism an `out` parameter? or a `select`? or a `return`? or a `print`? these are all different things that need to be accessed in different ways...

Comment: I've tried it with a couple of different stored procedures and the Read always returns false.  This particular example uses an out parameter.

Comment: also: why entlib? it is a **truly horrible** API, that is *at best* a leaky abstraction over raw ADO.NET, and *at worst* an ugly nuisance... just about *any other API I can think of* is a step up from entlib data access...

Comment: @SenorFree re "Read returns false": does it do a `select`? and does that `select` have at least one row?

Comment: The stored procedure works when I run it directly in SQL and its being used in another app so I don't think its the stored procedure.  Its should only return one row.

Comment: @SenorFree it is very hard for us to say much definitely about that without seeing what the sproc looks like...

Comment: I basically picked the simplest sproc in the database to test with.  its just a simple select

BEGIN TRY
SET @VersionNumber = (SELECT VersionNumber
                      FROM UTILITY_VERSION
                      WHERE UtilityVersionID = (SELECT MAX(UtilityVersionID) FROM UTILITY_VERSION))
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

  EXECUTE uspUtilityErrorHandler 0
END CATCH

Answer (score 0):

The main point of confusion is that the SQL statement you're using and the procedure you try to use do different things.

The SQL statement you use is:

```
SELECT VersionNumber FROM UTILITY_VERSION;
```

This will return a result set of no rows, one row or multiple rows.

The SQL code you gave for the stored procedure is:

```
TRY
    SET @VersionNumber = (SELECT VersionNumber FROM UTILITY_VERSION WHERE UtilityVersionID = (SELECT MAX(UtilityVersionID) FROM UTILITY_VERSION))
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXECUTE uspUtilityErrorHandler 0
END CATCH
```

This will **not** produce a result set, it'll simply set your output variable to some value. Therefore you'll have to use `ExecuteNonQuery` to execute it.

Try reading the result like this:

```
using (DbCommand cmd = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcName))
{
    DB.AddOutParameter(cmd, "VersionNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    DB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

    DBParameter par = cmd.Parameters["VersionNumber"];
    // par.Value should now hold the desired number ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an issue with a stored procedure as well.

my code :

```
    private static IDataReader GetDataReader(string procName)
    {
        DbCommand cmd = Db.GetStoredProcCommand(procName);
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        var dr = Db.ExecuteReader(cmd);
        return dr;
    }
```

This worked perfectly in the past, yet when I tried it now, it never returned any data.
Until I found that my procedure is selecting the records in a TRY block. Apparently, the DataReader doesn't like this.

When I removed the TRY-CATCH construction, the code started working as expected again.